# Number of results decreased after applying a query rule to promote a specific content type in SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-type, search-results, query-rule

As mentioned in the below link on how to promote a content type in SharePoint results: [How to change the order in which search results are displayed in SharePoint Server 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/10/03/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-server-2013/), 
I did the same but the problem is that the number of results are getting decreased when query rule is applied.

**For Example**: Without promoting query rule, Results are 150,
After applying query rule, Results are 10.

**Note**: The query rule works fine, it's promoting the specific content type to top.

Comment: Please provide an example of your query rule.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Final query text : (IsDocument:true) OR (contentclass:sts_listitem) AND (NOT contentclass:sts_web) (NOT contentclass:sts_site) XRANK(cb=5000.00) ContentType:***** ***

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I am not able to add a screenshot but what i can say is that  I only added the Dynamic ordering.
It was set to **Manual condition** and then specified **ContentType: ***** *** ** and selected **Promote to top** in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you limited search scope in your result source?

On your search results page, select to edit the Search Results Web Part->select Change query->select TEST tab->In the {searchboxquery} field enter a query->Test query->
Verify how much search result returned:

[image]

Comment: Chen As I said, The number of results decreased after applying the query.

Query Text for your reference:
(IsDocument:true) OR (contentclass:sts_listitem) AND (NOT contentclass:sts_web) (NOT contentclass:sts_site) XRANK(cb=5000.00) ContentType:***** ***

Comment: Chen  Below is the narrative of what i did in the **SORTING** tab of **Query Rules** in **Sharepoint Search Admin**

I added the Dynamic ordering.
It was set to **Manual condition** and then specified **ContentType: ***** *** ** and selected **Promote to top** in the dropdown.